# Combining php search array with query results - Inner join php arrays

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

I know i could do this with a set of loops, but just wondering if there is a more efficient way.

I have a 2D array with columns of 'id' and 'name' (it's dynamic).

And i query my database asking it to return all records that match the list of ids. That's all done.

Does anyone know how i could merge the query results with my initial array.

Long story short, i want to print out the only the names of ids that are in my database.

```
$array1 = [[1,'bob'],[2,'jim']];
$array2 = [[2,'false','true']];
```

i'd like output of:

```
$array3 = [[2,'jim','false','true']]
```

I guess a better description is that i'd like to inner join two arrays.

Comment: Please provide the structures of combining arrays

Comment: use `foreach` loop and make a query for each `id`

Comment: that would be pretty network intensive i think @iamsleepy

Answer (score 0):

Just as @Mihai said, you can use [array_intersect](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) to archive this.

So basically if you have 2 different arrays,

```
1. $array1 #results from the database
2. $array2 #results which you already have containing the ids
```

You can use the array_intersect which will compute the intersection of the arrays.

```
array array_intersect ($array1 ,$array2 );
```

Comment: Alas, that would only work if array1 and array2 had similar structures. If they did, i could just use array2.